# AngularJS check user state for each route

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular but I have managed to create an application and have managed to implement a login solution which looks like this:

```
angular.module('app.security', ['ngRoute', 'ngTouch'])

// ---
// ROUTES.
// ---

.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/security/login', {
        templateUrl: '/app/security/security.tpl.html'
    })
    .when('/security/logout', {
        resolve: {
            logout: ['$location', 'AuthService', function ($location, authService) {
                console.log(authService);

                authService.logout();
                $location.path('/security/login');
                $location.replace();
            }]
        }
    });
})

// ---
// CONTROLLERS.
// ---

.controller('LoginController', ['AuthService', '$location',
    function (authService, $location) {
        var self = this;

        self.user = { userName: '', password: '' };

        self.login = function () {
            authService.login(self.user).then(function (success) {
                $location.path('/');
            }, function (error) {
                self.errorMessage = (error) ? error.error_description : 'There was a serious error when attempting to login. Please contact an administrator.';
            })
        };
    }
])

// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.factory('AuthService', ['apiUrl', '$http', '$q', function (api, $http, $q) {
    var _authentication = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        userName: ""
    };

    var _login = function (loginData) {
        var data = "grant_type=password&username=" + loginData.userName + "&password=" + loginData.password;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(api + 'token', data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } })
            .success(function (response) {
                sessionStorage.authorizationData = angular.toJson({ token: response.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

                _authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
                _authentication.userName = loginData.userName;

                deferred.resolve(response);
            }).error(function (err, status) {
                _logOut();

                deferred.reject(err);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    var _logout = function () {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('authorizationData');
        _authentication.isAuthenticated = false;
        _authentication.userName = "";
    };

    var _init = function () {
        var authData = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.authorizationData);

        if (authData) {
            _authentication.isAuthenticated = true;
            _authentication.userName = authData.userName;
        }
    };

    _init(); // Constructor

    var service = {};

    service.login = _login;
    service.logout = _logout;
    service.authentication = _authentication;

    return service;
}])

.factory('AuthInterceptorService', ['$q', '$location', function ($q, $location) {
    var _request = function (config) {
        var authData = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.authorizationData);

        config.headers = config.headers || {};

        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
        }

        return config;
    }

    var _responseError = function (rejection) {
        if (rejection.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/security/login');
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

    var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

    authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
    authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

    return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);
```

This all works fine and I am happy with the result. As you can see, whenever I make an API request the interceptor checks to see if I have any **authData** and if I do it supplies the **accessToken** along with the API request. 
If I don't and there is a 401 error, then I am redirected to the login page.
Great :)

But what I would like to do, is when the first page loads is check to see if the **authData** exists and if it doesn't redirect to the login page.
What is the best way of doing this?

If you need more information, please let me know, I didn't want to bombard the question with unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $stateChangeStart event from the router. When ever the user is not loged in, you could redirect the user to the login page.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$exceptionHandler', '$state', 'AuthService',
function ($rootScope, $exceptionHandler, $state, AuthService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        // abort the state request when user is not authenticated
        if (!AuthService.isAuthentificated && toState.authentication !== "none") {
            event.preventDefault();

            // try if we could auto login the user cookie
            Authentication.autoLoginUserFromCookie().then(
                function success (respons) {
                    // continue with the requested state
                    $state.go(toState.name);
                },
                function fail (error) {
                    // no (valid) cookie
                    $state.go("login");
                }
            );
        }

    });
}]);
```

In the state provider I add a "authentication" property to each state

```
$stateProvider

            .state('login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'login.html'
                authentication : 'none'
            })
            .state('dashboard', {
                url: '/dashboard',
                templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
                authentication : 'user'
            })
    }]);
```